# JUnit Testing on functions in main()

Tags: java, junit

I want to write tests for my functions in my main class. Currently, I am creating an object in my JUnit test to be able to access the functions. I'm also having to recreate the data structures. Is this considered bad practice? Is there a better way to test main in JUnit?

Comment: You need to create objects in order to test methods, there is no way around. One notable thing though is **mocking**. That is, instead of creating real objects you may create fake implementations of a class that just **mock** some functionality, like user I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A main class should only be a thin wrapper around your application, which should otherwise be organized in logical modules. Test the modules individually, that should cover the majority of your code.

You may still call your main method in an integration test, probably just by invoking `YourMainclass.main(someArgArray)`. The interesting part is what you are basing your assertions on. If your app is text based, you will probably have to redirect System.out in your test method.